# What is a proper way to use model inside component in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

When calling `Partner` model from component it is showing error.

```
App::import("MyPlugin.Model", "Partner");
$objPartner = new Partner();
```

**Fatal error: Class 'Partner' not found in D:\htdocs\myapp\app\Plugin\MyPlugin\Controller\Component\TestComponent.php on line 287**

Comment: maybe you don't need to initializate a new model as you can acces your controller form the component and form the controller you can access any model thet is related to that controller

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never use App::import.
Always either use loadModel in controller or shell scope or the always working

```
$Partner = ClassRegistry::init('Partner');
```

Comment: In your case (model is inside a plugin), you would use:

    $Partner = ClassRegistry::init('MyPlugin.Partner');

Comment: When its a plugin, model, yes. The idea stays the same.

Comment: @mark,  Thanks for reply, but I want to know that what is wrong with the code I have written. And why you are suggesting to use ClassRegistry::init() instead of APP::import?

Comment: Just do it right and it will work. App::import() is outdated and only for third party vendor files these days.